# Android Gradle Plugin 8.2.0 , Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.0.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources

Tags: android-studio, opencv, gradle

I am adding an openCV module (opencv-4.8.0-android-sdk) to my project, in the manner of File->New->import module... . Then I get the error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40KJH.png)

I've tried everything I found on stackoverflow but none of the solutions work. Does anyone have any solution that might help me?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error today. It turns out, my project uses build.gradle.kts & settings.gradle.kts and importing openCV creates (not modifying) corrupted build.gradle and settings.gradle.

Simply delete the odd `.gradle` files newly created by the openCV (those directly under project root directory, not one under openCV sdk directory) solved the problem for me.

note: After deleting the `.gradle` files, the initial problem was solved, however, the second problem followed right away. That was "namespace" thingy and it was gone after modifying `build.gradle` of the openCV sdk.

```
    compileSdkVersion 26
    namespace 'org.opencv' // add this line
    defaultConfig {
```